# How to use generic class (or interface) in another generic class (or interface) with the same data type parameters without casting

Tags: java, interface, parameters, casting, generics

I need the Cache class that keep the `<TKey key, TValue value>` pairs. And it is desirable that `TKey` can be any class that supports `Serializable` interface and `TValue` can be any  class that supports `Serializable` and my own `ICacheable` interfaces.

There is another `CacheItem` class that keeps `<TKey key, TValue value>` pair.
I want the Cache class has the `void add(CacheItem cacheItem)` method. Here is my code:

```
public class Cache<TKey extends Serializable, 
   TValue extends Serializable & ICacheable >
{
 private Map<TKey, TValue> cacheStore = 
     Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<TKey, TValue>());

 public void add(TKey key, TValue value)
 {
  cacheStore.put(key, value);
 }

 public void add(CacheItem cacheItem)
 {   
  TKey key = cacheItem.getKey();
  //Do not compiles. Incompatible types. Required: TValue. Found: java.io.Serializable
  TValue value = (TValue) cacheItem.getValue();
  //I need to cast to (TValue) here to compile
  //but it gets the Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to 'TValue'
  add(key, value);
 }
}
```

In another file:

```
public class CacheItem<TKey extends Serializable, 
  TValue extends Serializable & ICacheable>
{
 TKey key;
 TValue value;

 public TValue getValue()
 {
  return value;
 }

 public TKey getKey()
 {
  return key;
 }
}
```

Is there anything I could do to avoid casting?

Comment: @Sergey I edited your code, to format the code. It's much easier to read and understand :-) I hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: KLE, I totally agree, after editing the code is much more easier to read.

Comment: There is no need to use I for interfaces.  the I doesn't add anything useful - nobody should care if it is an interface or not.  It would especially suck if, for some reason, it had to change to an abstract class at a later date since now the name would be wrong (you probably would add an abstract class instead, but the point is that yiou are not adding anything by putting I there).

Comment: TofuBeer, thanks for your comment. The I letter came from C# here. But I'll take into account your comment and will rewrite my code to not use the I letter in the names of my interfaces.

Comment: Yeah I think that COM picked that habit up from windows with hungarian notation... lpsz sort of thing.  Made sense (sort of) for C when the compiler didn't do as good a job at checking the types... but in a "real" C compiler no need for it now, and it really defeats the purpose in an OO language.  Very often you will change the type of something which means you either have to change the name (cannot do it if it is non-private) or the encoded name means nothing any more (which is annoying and possibly dangerous).

Comment: A really good book for naming (and a whole not of other things) is "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin: http://books.google.com/books?id=dwSfGQAACAAJ&dq=clean+code

Comment: Thanks for advices, TofuBeer. I'll look for this book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `add` method signature look like this :

```
public void add(CacheItem<TKey, TValue> cacheItem)
```

Comment: This was VERY helpful answer! The problem dissolved immediately. Many many thanks to Bozho!

Answer (score 2):

```
    public void add(CacheItem<TKey, TValue> cacheItem) {
    TKey key = cacheItem.getKey();
    TValue value = cacheItem.getValue();
    add(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the raw type on CacheItem. Try this signature:

```
  public void add(CacheItem<TKey, TValue> cacheItem)
```

That will require that the CacheItem have the same generic parameters as the Cache.

Comment: Yishai, your comment further clears the issue for me. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you could make `ICacheable` extends `Serializable`, that would simplify your code.

---

Could you try to **parameterize the method add's parameter**?

```
public class Cache<TKey extends Serializable, 
   TValue extends Serializable & ICacheable >
{
 ...
 public void add(CacheItem<TKey, TValue> cacheItem)
 {   
  TKey key = cacheItem.getKey();
  TValue value = cacheItem.getValue();
  add(key, value);
 }
}
```

---

Because CacheItem is a parameterized class, most references to it should use the parameters.
Otherwise, it still has unresolved types, and you are confronted to `casts`.

Comment: KLE, Thanks for your comment. It clears why do I need to write CacheItem<TKey, TValue> and not simply CacheItem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your class like below

```
public class Cache<TKey extends Serializable, 
   TValue extends Serializable & ICacheable >
{
 private Map<Serializable, Serializable> cacheStore = 
     Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Serializable, Serializable>());

 public void add(Serializable key, Serializable value)
 {
  cacheStore.put(key, value);
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void add(CacheItem cacheItem)
 {   
  Serializable key = cacheItem.getKey();
  //Do not compiles. Incompatible types. Required: TValue. Found: java.io.Serializable
  Serializable value = cacheItem.getValue();
  //I need to cast to (TValue) here to compile
  //but it gets the Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to 'TValue'
  add(key, value);
 }

}
```

Comment: DKSRathore, thanks for your answer, but it is a little bit not what I really want. In reality I would use the value.GetBytesUsed() method of the ICacheable interface which this variable implements:  
TValue value = cacheItem.getValue() ;
int bytes = value.GetBytesUsed();
But I need to cast in your code:  
Serializable value = cacheItem.getValue();
int bytes = ((ICacheable)value).GetBytesUsed();  

I want to avoid casting wherever it is possible.